# Unable to install the latest package from GitHub

Tags: r, github, shiny, r-package

My team is working on a new tool using R, R Shiny and GitHub.  I am trying to Build and Install the new package on my RStudio (using Build and Install options).  Under R Studio, I am able to Pull the code from the GitHub repo.  However when I try to Build it (using "Install" option), I get an error that there are a few packages are not available.  These packages are available under the project but I still get this error message.  When I do a renv::restore() in the console, I get a message that the library is already synchronized.  I have included a screenshot of what I see below.  I have tried deleting and re-installing the application but it is of now use.  My colleague who is working on this application under the same server and the same repo does not face any issue at all.   Also I am facing this issue from around the time I created a branch under Git about a month ago for another project we are working on.  I did not face an issue prior to that.  Could the new branch have caused this issue?  Can someone help resolve this issue please?

[image: Image from my RStudio]

I tried deleting and re-installing the package.  Update R Studio to a newer version. I have tried devtools, install_packages but to no avail. This application used to work well till around the time I created a branch to push some code.  When I try to run the application, it still refers to the previous version (asking for some excel file which are no longer needed in the updated version).

Should I be deleting my GitHub profile and creating a new one?

Comment: What packages are listed as dependencies in the DESCRIPTION file of the package?

Comment: These are the ones listed:

Comment: @philThese are the ones listed:   Imports: config (>= 0.3.1), dplyr,  forcats, fresh,  ggiraph,   ggplot2,   ggthemes,   gh, golem (>= 0.3.5),   gt, haven, htmltools,jsonlite,kableExtra, leaflet, lubridat,   magrittr,openxlsx,packcircles,patchwork,plotly, progress,purrr,quarto,    reactable,reactablefmtr,readr,readxl,rintrojs,rlang,rmarkdown,scales, shiny (>= 1.7.2),shinyalert,shinyBS,shinycssloaders,shinydashboard, shinydashboardPlus, shinydisconnect, shinyjs, shinymanager, shinytoastr, shinyWidgets,sortable, stringr,tidygeocoder,tidyr,tidytext, timevis, tippy,treemapify, viridis, waiter,zip